# Замена последовательности букв на пробел

Tags: c++

По условию задания надо заменять последовательность букв на пробел, например:

> Идет: abcdf45d23 Должно стать: 45 23

```
int main()
{    
    ofstream fout;
    ifstream fin;
    string str;
    char char0;
    cout << "stroka dlya faila: ";
    getline(cin, str);
    fout.open("Dz.txt");
    fout << str;
    fout.close();
    fin.open("Dz.txt");

    while (fin.get(char0))
    {
        if (char0 > 47 && char0 < 58)
            cout << char0;
        else
            cout << " ";

    }
}
```

Но пробел ставится при встрече любой буквы, как можно модернизировать программу?

Comment: Используйте std::string. Итерируйтесть по строке  через рейндж-байзед фор, делать проверку is_digit если нет = " ". Что сложного? дальше подуйте как много пробелов превратить в 1, и проверить 1 и последний элемент на пробел.

Comment: 1) "можете модернизировать программу?" - это не вопрос, никто не будет делать что-то за вас. 2) какой ожидаемый результат? - программа заменяет все буквы на пробелы, что вас не устраивает?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch ощущение будто бы вы вообще поверхностно прочитали то, что я написал. Я не писал "можете модернизировать программу", я написал "как это сделать", это разные вещи. Плюс ожидаемый результат написан, впредь перед тем как что то написать, прочитайте повнимательнее пожалуйста, вместо того чтобы лишь бы что то написать

Comment: @David по поводу 1-ого - действительно, недоглядел (без очков не правильно прочитал), но второй - не снимается: программа заменит все буквы на пробелы, в результате чего: abcdf45d23 станет 45 23 - что вас не устраивает?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch я же написал, заменяется последовательность букв на пробел, то есть если букв 5,17,2297, не важно, будет один пробел, до следующей цифры, после цифры если снова идут буквы снова пробел, но опять же, только один должен быть

Comment: @David окей, а теперь ещё поясните: почему одна буква - это тоже последовательность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool space = false;
while (fin.get(char0))
{
    if (char0 > 47 && char0 < 58){
        cout << char0;
        space = true;
    }
    else
        if (space){
           cout << " ";
           space = false;
        }
}
```